# the model object is returning null

Tags: c#, .net

I am using dotnet core 2.1.the problem is that when my database has values and I am querying it, it returns the value in the UserInteractions model but It says that the User Object is null. although it is not null.  my models and query are as below:

```
public class UserInteractions {
public int Id { get; set; }
public int? UserId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey ("UserId")] public User user { get; set; }
public int? TargetId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey ("TargetId")] public User target { get; set; }
public int NumberOfMusicMedia { get; set; }
public int VolumeOfMusicMedia { get; set; }
public int NumberOfImageMedia { get; set; }
public int VolumeOfImageMedia { get; set; }
public int NumberOfVideoMedia { get; set; }
public int VolumeOfVideoMedia { get; set; }
public int NumberOfDocumentMedia { get; set; }
public int VolumeOfDocumentMedia { get; set; }
public bool IsMuted { get; set; } 
}

public class User {
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Phone { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

this is my query:

```
var mediaInfo =  _db.UserInteractions.FirstOrDefault (o => o.UserId == 2);
User inf = mediaInfo.target;
```

it says that inf is null, but it should not be null

Comment: Try `_db.UserInteractions.Include(x => x.Target).FirstOrDefault(o => o.UserId == 2);` You can check out [Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data) here.

Comment: @Rango he/she is trying to access `mediaInfo.target`. And the question specifically state that `it returns the value in the UserInteractions model but It says that the User Object is null`.

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` will return `null`, the default, if there's no user with ID==2. That's what the code explicitly asked for. What is the question?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Your are correct. It would'nt throw. However, he/she is not talking about an NRE. Read the question please.

Comment: @CemYILMAZ and even with lazy loading if there was a related user, it would be returned. This would result in an extra query though. If `target` is null right after loading the `mediainfo` object, there's no related User

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing you are trying to do is using Lazy Loading in Entity Framework.

To load that on runtime you have to use:

```
.Include(x => x.target)
```

**EDIT**: Entity Framework Core is not supporting Lazy loading yet. You can use lazy loading currently only with Entity Framework.

Please adjust your spelling since you are inconsisten with naming (mixing camel and pascal case)

Comment: thanks. this solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

If the Foreign key are correctly configured you can use .Include(c=>c.YourProperty).

Comment: He is accessing since he wrote : mediaInfo.target;

Comment: what are you saying ? Look at the question, please : var mediaInfo =  _db.UserInteractions.FirstOrDefault (o => o.UserId == 2);
User inf = mediaInfo.target;

Comment: Noone said that he is getting NRE, the only thing written in question is that after accesing:" it returns the value in the UserInteractions model but It says that the User Object is null" So UserInteractions is not null but targer which was not included is null.

Comment: Even with lazy loading, trying to access `.target` right after loading a user wouldn't return null if there *was* a matching `User`. `Include` isn't necessary when the origianl DbContext is available. Most likely, the relation is *not* configured or there is no related `User` record